# Echo not receiving pusher client event sent to same user

Tags: laravel, echo, pusher, laravel-echo

In my Vue app, I have broadcast a client event to the user itself. Means if the app is open in multiple devices, I want to update the data in realtime in each device when a message is seen by the user. So I did below within a method-

```
Echo.private("chat." + this.authUser.id).whisper("seen", {
   user: this.chatUser,
});
```

where the **authUser** is currently logged in user.
I can see the event is received in pusher debug console with no error. But I can't listen to that client event in my code.
But the typing event is working perfectly. My typing event is -

```
Echo.private("chat." + this.chatUser.id).whisper("typing", {
   user: this.authUser,
});
```

The difference between the **typing** & **seen** event is typing event is sent to other user but seen event is sent to the same user.

```
     Echo.private("chat." + this.authUser.id)
      .listenForWhisper("typing", (e) => {
        console.log(e)
      })
      .listenForWhisper("seen", (e) => {
        console.log(e);
      })
```

Comment: Why `seen` event is sent to the same user? Just asking..afaik, seen event should be sent to other user, right?

Comment: Suppose the chat is opened in 2 different devices, say like your WhatsApp web is open & also WhatsApp mobile app is open. So, when you read a message, it should be removed from unread messages in both devices.